# Key of array as a parameter in function php

Tags: php, arrays

I try to pass a key of an array in parameter in my function like that

```
function getStats($array , $key){

    $data = array_sum(array_map(function($item) { 
        return $item[$key]; 
    }, $array));

    return $data;
}

$stats = getStats($myarray , 'nb_view');
```

It doesn't work but this works

```
function getStats($array){

    $data = array_sum(array_map(function($item) { 
        return $item['nb_view']; 
    }, $array));
    return $data;
}

$stats = getStats($array);
```

Comment: please post array over here:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When defining your anonymous function, the `use` keyword allows you to [inherit variables from the parent scope](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-200).

```
function getStats($array , $key){

    $data = array_sum(array_map(function($item) use($key) { 
        return $item[$key]; 
    }, $array));

    return $data;
}
```